# Thymeleaf dropdown not populating

Tags: java, html, drop-down-menu, dictionary, thymeleaf

**I have a simple Enum which will contain various locales:**

```
public enum LocaleEnum {
en_US,es_MX;

private static EnumMap<LocaleEnum, String> map = new EnumMap<LocaleEnum, String>(LocaleEnum.class);

// Pre-load the descriptive values.  Will pull the descriptive value from a property file later.
static {
    String desc = "English";
    for (LocaleEnum locale : LocaleEnum.values()) {
        map.put(locale, desc);
        desc = "Espanol";
    }
}

public static EnumMap<LocaleEnum, String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
```

}

**I then have a method on a model to pass the EnumMap to the view:**

```
public EnumMap<LocaleEnum, String> getLocales() {
    EnumMap<LocaleEnum, String> map = LocaleEnum.getMap();
    return map;
}
```

**I am now trying to display those values in a dropdown using Thymeleaf:**

```
<select th:field="*{locales}">
    <option value="NONE">---- Select ----</option>
    <option th:each="locale : ${locales}"
            th:value="${locale.key}"
            th:text="${locale.value}">Englishy</option>
</select>
```

**I get the "---- Select ----" in the dropdown.  In debug mode, I see the getLocales() method getting called along with the values in the EnumMap.**

**However, there is nothing else in the dropdown.  I keep comparing my implementation to various others, but I'm not seeing my failure.  All thoughts are more than welcome.  Thanks.**

Comment: I think `EnumMap` bound in jsp is not good idea, how use other map with `String` ??

Comment: Wundwin, I'm not certain I understand your concern with the EnumMap.  Can you explain your concerns?  Since this is my first usage of an EnumMap, I'm interested to understand what issues you think I might be facing in using one in this instance.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks OhioCowboy & Wundwin I really appreciate your help with this.

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  All I needed to do was change:

```
<option th:each="locale : ${locales}"
```

to

```
<option th:each="locale : *{locales}"
```

Which now that I'm getting to understand the markup, makes sense.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses your enum more effectively. I see why your using map so you can pass the whole collection, but there is a better way using `.values()` see below

```
public enum LocaleEnum
{
    en_US("en_US", "English"), es_MX("es_MX", "Espanol");

    private final String locale;
    private final String desc;

    LocaleEnum(String locale, String desc)
    {
         this.locale = locale;
         this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getLocale()
    {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Then change your method that adds the enum to the model to. Note `.values()` is a static method for enums that returns an array.

```
public LocaleEnum getLocales()
{
    return LocaleEnum.values();
}
```

so then your thymeleaf page then looks like

```
<select th:field="*{locales}">
    <option value="NONE">---- Select ----</option>
    <option th:each="locale : ${locales}"
            th:value="${locale.getLocale()}"
            th:text="${locale.getDesc()}">Englishy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OhioCowboy, First thank you for the response.  I implemented your code.  I made 2 minor changes to remove some errors: 1. changed public LocalEnum getLocales() to public LocalEnum[] getLocales()  2. changed <option value="NONE"> to <option value="en_US">.  Once I did that, it all ran, but the values in the dropdown still did not populate (except the "--- Select ---".  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that the model is being populated with the LocaleEnum? with adding @ModelAttribute("locales") above public LocalEnum[] getLocales() method?

Comment: FFR: I have replaced `th:each="locale : ${locales}"` with `th:each="locale : *{locales}"` as suggested by @forevernewb123 in his answer and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

How try map with `<String, String>` types?

#### LocaleEnum

```
public enum LocaleEnum {
    EN_US("en_US", "English"), ES_MX("es_MX", "Espanol");

    private final String locale;
    private final String lang;

    LocaleEnum(String locale, String lang) {
        this.locale = locale;
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getLocalesAsMap() {
        Map<String, String> localeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        localeMap.put(EN_US.getLocale(), EN_US.getLang());
        localeMap.put(ES_MX.getLocale(), ES_MX.getLang());
        return localeMap;
    }
}
```

#### Model to pass enum values to page

```
public Map<String, String> getLocales() {        
    return LocaleEnum.getLocalesAsMap();
}
```

#### Dropdown on Thymeleaf page

In the case `Iterable`, let's iterate map's entries with `locales.entrySet()`

```
<select th:field="*{locales}">
    <option value="NONE">---- Select ----</option>
    <option th:each="locale : ${locales.entrySet()}"
        th:value="${locale.key}"
        th:text="${locale.value}">Englishy</option>
</select>
```